# idangero.us swiper - "Swiper not defined" error

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I've recently tried to set up a "idangero.us Swiper" feature on my site. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working. My experience with JS is very limited so I'm at a complete loss on how to fix this.

The error I receive is `Uncaught ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined`

Thank you for any help you can give.
http://www.hollywoodfeed.com/pages/catalog-page-1

My HTML is

```
<!-- Swiper -->
<style>
.swiper-container{
width:100%;
height:auto;
margin:20px auto;
}
.swiper-slide{     
text-align:center;
font-size:18px;
background:#fff;
line-height:300px;
}
</style>

<div class="swiper-container">
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
</div>

<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

<div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
<!-- Swiper Include Files -->
<script>  {{ 'swiper.min.js' | asset_url }}</script>

<script>
  var swiper;
  $(document).ready(function () {
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationType: 'fraction'
})
});
</script>
```

Comment: What does `<script>  {{ 'swiper.min.js' | asset_url }}</script>` output in the HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me that whatever templating system you are using isn't putting the dependency script file on the page.

```
<!-- Swiper Include Files -->
<script>  {{ 'swiper.min.js' | asset_url }}</script>
```

The above script outputs the below:

```
<script>     
  //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0659/4529/t/75/assets/swiper.min.js?10728068994914913511
</script>
```

The reference to the script file shouldn't be inside the script element itself. Instead it should be in the script tags `src` attribute.
Like so:

```
<script src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0659/4529/t/75/assets/swiper.min.js?10728068994914913511">
</script>
```

---

### tl;dr

The swiper dependencies were missing. You need to include them properly.

Comment: absolutely correct solution.... in fact you need to use your ```https://<your storename e.g. xyz.com>//cdn.shopify.com/.......>```. Don't forget 'double black slashes' before cdn and long long integer appearing at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error even if you don't put the script tag linking the swiper.js files at the top in the head section.